# How to add multiple tags in bamboo plan variable?

Tags: cicd, bamboo, bamboo-specs, bamboo-artifacts

how to add multiple tags in a bamboo plan variable for execution.

I tried with @tag1, @tag2. but its not working. its giving error giving oio.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: Failed to parse 'cucumber.filter.tags' with value @tag1, tag2